# mule expression transformer exception

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a payload like

```
{"jcr:createdBy":"admin","jcr:content":{"sling:resourceType":"contentpage","addressdetails":{"state":"vic"}}}
```

I want to change the value of state. I have tried the below,

```
<expression-transformer
                    expression="#[message.payload.jcr:content.addressdetails.state = 'NSW';message.payload]"
                    doc:name="Expression" />
```

but this throws an exception, invalid expression.
I believe its because of : in jcr:createdBy. How should I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />` before expression like following :-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap" />
<expression-transformer expression="#[message.payload.jcr.content:addressdetails.state = 'NSW';message.payload]"  doc:name="Expression" />
```

Comment: Sorry. I should have mentioned this earlier.I am using this. Also i have a logger which works fine like this #[message.payload.get('jcr:content').get('addressdetails').get('state'). Idont know how to set the value.

Comment: Pls provide the exception you are getting

Comment: Use Groovy script .. you can make the same in a easy way

Comment: if only i knew groovy script.

Comment: One more thing, in your value jcr:content.addressdetails .. the symbol : is the main responsible for causing invalid expression

Comment: Groovy script is almost same as how you have constucted here .. for example :- you can assing like message.payload.name='abc' and at last return the payload like return message.payload  as what you have done here .. It's almost same way what you have done ..